# MonadIO to Maybe

Tags: haskell, sparse-matrix, monads

I've been using HMatrix for linear algebra and it's `linearSolve` function has the straightforward (albeit terse) type:

```
linearSolve :: Field t => Matrix t -> Matrix t -> Maybe (Matrix t)
```

I'd like to try out the `sparse-linear-algebra` library and it's `<\>` function (not the `<\>` function in HMatrix), which has type:

```
(<\>) :: (MonadIO m, MonadThrow m) => MatrixType v -> v -> m v
```

While I'd like to use the additional information that this provides, I'd like to start with just a drop-in replacement of type:

```
MatrixType v -> v -> Maybe v
```

so that I don't have rewrite my code all the way back up to `main`. How can I do that?

I'm fairly new to Haskell and still at the "Oh! I understand monads now. No! Wait! It's gone again" phase.

Thanks

Comment: Note to library authors: if you want the ability to print debug info, use MonadLogger instead of MonadIO.

Comment: Offending statement: https://github.com/ocramz/sparse-linear-algebra/blob/84d4fbf7aeec75e77de9628443d87ecd96fe7908/src/Control/Iterative.hs#L184

Comment: This seems to be a very bleeding edge library: its last upload on Hackage is nine days ago! If you wish to use that library, you might be able to contact the developer (Marco Zocca) and ask him to remove the IO dependency. You can also point him to this question. This might be an actually reasonable use case for that `unsafe` function which should not be named, e.g. if IO is only needed to access an underlying pure C function. If it is used only for logging, IO is overkill.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. That MonadIO constraint is unsightly I agree and is due to some old debugging constructs; up until not so long ago the library didn't have many users which is why its rough edges are still exposed. I was hoping to have such discussions somewhere more appropriate like the `sparse-linear-algebra` issue tracker rather than by public shaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments it seems like:

1. Once you're in `Monad IO` there is no escape. As such, the answer to the original newbie Haskeller question is "you can't"
2. The library author, @ocramz, had existing plans to use `MonadLogger` and we may see something as part of an upcoming redesign